# Getting a warning when passing struct through function

Tags: c, function, struct, typedef

I'm trying to pass a whole structure through a function by value, and I test if the pass was successful by displaying the variables in the structure that was passed.

When I compile and run the program, the variables display correctly, but I get a warning:

> warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration

So it refers to the function prototype being declared with parameter names that had no types? But if I declared the function correctly, why am I getting this warning?

Also, in the short program I wrote to test this, the warning doesn't affect the fact that the output being displayed is correct.

But if I were to get this warning under the same circumstances (passing struct through function) when writing a larger-scale program, will it affect the output in that program being correct?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void pass(Info);

typedef struct {
    char str[10];
    int num;
} Info;

void main() {
    Info i;

    strcpy(i.str, "Hello!");
    i.num = 1;

    pass(i);
}

void pass(Info i) {
    printf("%s\n", i.str);
    printf("%d\n", i.num);
}
```

Output:

> Hello!
>
> 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `typedef` statement *after* the usage of the newly defined type (*synonym for another type, to be nitpicky*). At that point, in the function forward declaration, compiler does not know a type named `Info`. So, it assumes it to be a variable name.

Move the `typedef` before function prototype.

That said, `void main()` is not a valid signature for `main()` in a hosted environment. It should be `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you. And I'll take note of the `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are declare the function prototype before the Info structure declaration.

An alternative could be the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char str[10];
    int num;
} Info;

void pass(Info);

void main() 
{
      Info i;

      strcpy(i.str, "Hello!");
      i.num = 1;
      pass(i)
}

void pass(Info i) 
{
     printf("%s\n", i.str);
     printf("%d\n", i.num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler considers this function declaration

```
void pass(Info);
```

as a function declaration with an identifier list. That is here `Info` is identifier of the parameter not its type.

However according to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)):

> 3 **An identifier list** in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function **shall be empty**.

SO the compiler issues a warning that the identifier list is not empty for the function declaration that is not a function definition.

```
warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

Either you should write

```
void pass();
```

Or you should place the typedef of the structure declaration before the function declaration and in this case the name `Info`  will denote a type.